# Why my mongoose schema add an array on top of my current array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm querying a mongo document to retrieve the array info. The thing is my array is inside another array. I don't know how this happened. I'm force to map twice every time to get inside. Anyone knows why?

Here's the mongoose schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongo = require("mongodb");

const insertedLaw = require("./civilcode_section2_21.json");

const Law = mongoose.model(
    "Laws",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        law_name: String,
        section_name: String,
        section_text: [String],
    }),
);

// Law.insertMany(insertedLaw); (commented out because using Nodemon)

exports.Law = Law;
```

Here's my node route:

```js
const express = require("express");

const {
  Law,
} = require("../models/law");



const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const laws = await Law.find();
  res.send(laws);

});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's my Jsx:

```js
const urlLaw = "http://localhost:3000/api/laws";

class Dashboard extends Component {
    state = {
        laws: {},
        sectionText: [],
        
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getLaws();
        
    }
    getLaws = async () => {
        try {
            const { data: laws } = await http.get(urlLaw);
            const sectionText = laws.map((law) => law.section_text);
            this.setState({ laws, sectionText });
            console.log("You data has been received!");
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex.response && ex.response === 404) alert("error receiving data");
        }
    };
```

Here's the result in console:

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBqFn.png)

Here's my Mongo Document:

[mongodoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FygO.png)

I can fetch the data but I feel it will become very clunky as I add more query. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your console.log image shows the result of await http.get(urlLaw).

You get nested arrays because in MongoDB and mongoose, "find" returns an array of documents. If you had more than one Law in your Laws collection, it would be clearer since you would see that this second document is returned too.

To sum up, the "outer" array is the array of the documents found by MongoDB and the "inner" array is the section_text field you want.

Use findOne if you want a document to be returned instead of an array of documents.

Comment: Wow. Such an easy fix. THANKS!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped.